# Python closest subset sum function

Tags: dynamic-programming, python, subset-sum

I'm writing a closestSubset(s,A) function that takes an integer s and an array of positive integers A and returns an array consisting of elements of A which add up to s. If there is no subset that adds up to s, I want the function to instead return the subset which adds up to the value closest to s.

For example:

> if A is [12, 79, 99, 91, 81, 47] and s is 150, it will return [12, 91,
> 47] as 12+91+47 is 150
>
> if A is [15, 79, 99, 6, 69, 82, 32] and s is 150 it will return [69,
> 82] as 69+82 is 151, and there is no subset of A whose sum is 150.

```
# Driver code:
A = [15, 79, 99, 6, 69, 82, 32]
subset = closestSubset(5000,A)
```

I understand how to produce this function if the correct numbers exist to form integer s but when there isn't, then how do I find the closest? Would I have to actually create a left and right range so that if for example the integer was 150, then any number closest to 150 by for e.g. 10 would be fine?

code:

```
def closestSubset(s,A):
        return closestSubsetRec(s,A,len(A))
    
    def closestSubsetRec(s,A,i):
        #s is zero
        if s == 0:
            return []
        #no subset that adds up to s    
        if i == 0 and s!= 0:
            return   
        # else, check if sum can be obtained by any of the following 
        # (a) including the last element 
        # (b) excluding the last element    
        withIt = closestSubsetRec(s,A, i-1)  
        withoutIt = closestSubsetRec(s-A[i-1],A,i-1)
         # (b) excluding last element fails
        if withIt == None:
         # (a) including last element fails
            if withoutIt == None:            
                 # (a) including last element successes
                    return 
            else: 
                return append(withoutIt,A[i-1])
        return withIt

A =  [12, 79, 99, 91, 81, 47] 
B = [15, 79, 99, 6, 69, 82, 32]

print(closestSubset(150,A)) 
print(closestSubset(150,B))
```

Comment: Hi, programming questions are off-topic here. If you have a question about algorithms, we would be glad to see [pseudo-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) instead.

Comment: Does my paragraph explanation not count as pseudo?

Comment: Anything that is not language-specific is good, hence an explanation paragraph is good as well :)